# How to use multiple router-outlet in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, router, router-outlet

I have a main `router-outlet`, which is used to display a login screen (`/login`) and the main content screen(which is shown after login) (`/main`).

Once the user is on content screen, I want to show a nav-bar on top, with 2 options(say, 'Overview', 'Insights'). This nav-bar is common for `OverviewComponent` and `InsightsComponent`

Below this nav-bar, I want to show another router-outlet, which would load `OverviewComponent` or `InsightsComponent`, based on what user clicks in nav-bar.  If I give '/overview' and /'insights' as the route, it would directly show me the respective component, but not the nav-bar.

Following is my current routing config (this is not right):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component:  MainComponent},
  { path: 'overview', component:  OverviewComponent},
  { path: 'insights', component: InsightsComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Kindly let me know if we can achieve this in angular2  angular4. I'm using following version:

```
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0"
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0"
"@angular/cli": "1.0.1"
```

******************Attempt 2 - Still not working******************

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: MainComponent },
      { path: 'overview', component:  OverviewComponent },
      { path: 'insights', component: InsightsComponent },
    ]

  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

*******Attempt 2 - Sudo Code with all components - Still not working*******

```
//app.component.html

<router-outlet></router-outlet>


//app.module.ts

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main',
    children: [
      { path: '', component: MainComponent },
      { path: 'overview', component:  OverviewComponent },
      { path: 'insights', component: InsightsComponent },
    ]

  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

//login.component.html
<div class="text-center vertical-center">
    <form>
        <div class="horizontal">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal">
            <label for="">Password</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="" value="">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="navigate()">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>

//login.component.ts
navigate() {
    this.router.navigate(['./main']);
  }

//main.component.html

<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


//app.header.html

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class=""><a routerLink="/main/overview" routerLinkActive="active">OVERVIEW</a></li>
                <li class=""><a routerLink="/main/insights" routerLinkActive="active">INSIGHTS</a></li>
            </ul>

//overview.html
<p>This is overview section</p>

//insights.html
<p>This is insights section</p>
```

********Attempt 3 - Working**********

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: MainComponent },
      { path: 'overview', component:  OverviewComponent },
      { path: 'insights', component: InsightsComponent },
    ]

  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: Can I see how is your main.component.html look like?

Comment: `<!--MainComponent.html-->
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

<!--AppHeader.html-->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class=""><a href="/main/overview">OVERVIEW</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="/main/insights">INSIGHTS</a></li>
            </ul>`

Comment: Couldn't solve it by adding the routerLink in the app-header? If it's not working what's the error you're getting? -You can edit the question with particular code. Would be much clear.-

Comment: You have two options: you can define a child router outlet or a secondary (auxiliary) router outlet. See the docs for more info: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Hi Saiyaff, I did try routerLink before href, that didn't work either. There is no error thrown. When I click 'Overview' or 'Insights', screen shows me Overview or Insight component, without the header, which is present in maincomponent.

Comment: Hi Deborah, The example shows with only one router outlet. I have 2 router outlets. Are there examples that you can guide me for child router outlet?

Comment: Silly me! I missed adding MainComponent as component in module.ts
`const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: MainComponent },
      { path: 'overview', component:  OverviewComponent },
      { path: 'insights', component: InsightsComponent },
    ]
  
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];`

It works fine now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So if I get the question right you want to have login screen initially and after the user logs in, you want him to see /main where navigation is shown. Both login screen and main application should have a different layout.

We have a similar case and using LayoutComponent. Here's simplified example.

```
// This is main component that get's bootstrapped that has 'top-level' router.
@Component({selector: 'app', template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'})
class AppComponent {}

// main router config
// Here AuthModule has router with login and logout configured and LoginGuard
// redirect the user to /auth/login when she is not authenticated.
// We're using lazy-loading but you can use direct component instead
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'auth', loadChildren: '../modules/+auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [LoginGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'main', loadChildren: '../modules/+main/main.module#MainModule'}
    ]
  }
];

// AuthModule/LoginComponent has own template and it will be rendered
// into 'top-level' router-outlet.

// LayoutComponent
// Here you define your main application layout that can include navigation
// and anything else that are global to the app. It has another router-outlet
// that get rendered when the layout is accessible (which in this case when the user is authenticated).
@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  template: `
    <div id="wrapper">
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
      <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg dashboard-1" adjust-content-height>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
    <notifications></notifications>
    <error-modal></error-modal>
  `
})
export class LayoutComponent {}

// Auth/LoginComponent can have its own template that will have different layout from the main application
```

So the flow would be like so:

- when the user tries to load / then she redirected to /main
- if the user is not authenticated she redirected to /auth/login else she loads /main

Hope that helps.

EDIT:
Updated [sickelap/ng-starter](https://github.com/sickelap/ng-starter) repository with example app that has:

- routing with lazy-loading
- layouts
- and other things

Comment: But this is great, I infact, wanted my views to get lazy loaded. I thought my code above was getting lazy loaded. Just one question, is `APP_ROUTES` within main app.component.ts (which is what it is in the code) or is it part of app.module.ts?

Comment: I'm keeping APP_ROUTES in app.routes.ts file and using them in app.module.ts. After answering this question I started to think that it would be a great idea to share project structure as working example for utilising a lot of good stuff in using angular. I know that there's a ton of boilerplates and starters but as everyone else, I'd like to do it "My Way™" :) I created repo https://github.com/sickelap/ng-starter which is empty atm but working on that right now and will have something useful in a few days.

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. Yes, there are so many cool stuff in A2, which many aren't aware and sometimes hard to find snippets. Your starter kit, for sure will help many. Do drop a comment, when it's done, so that all of us can have a look at it. Thanks again. I like 'Your Way' ;)

Comment: Updated repo with example app. This is work-in-progress and I will be updating it from time to time with features I will come up or from suggestions. I quite enjoyed it

Answer (score 0):

I think i gather what you are trying to achieve. Can i recommend that you use a variable to mimic some kind of state change, and assign that to the component view.
  have your app.component.html only contain a router outlet.
  create a new main.component.html that replicates the existing component.html

```
`<app-header></app-header>`
```

replace the href in the  with *`(click)="handleChange(<linkValue>)'"`

So each link would look as below.

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> <li class=""><a href="/main/overview">OVERVIEW</a></li>`

`handleChange` method: 
declare the currentLink - `public currentLink string;`
`// or 
 public currentLink: string = '<a default value>';`
`public handleChange(link: string) {
   this.currentLink = link;
}`

create a view.component.

example selector `<view [link]='currentLink'></view>`

give the view component an 
    `@Input() public link: string;`

```
back to view.component.html
```

`<div id="overview" *ngIf="link = 'overview'">overview content</div>`
   `<div id="main" *ngIf="link = 'main'">overview content</div>`

You can then refactor those into seperate child components.

Overview: 
   You are making the app-header a global component that handles a 'link' variable. I would recommend taking a look into ngRx or general app-state methods. As this can be a great way to manage UI.

Comment: Thanks for the help Verix, I got it working now. But yeah, that's a potential alternative, which I'll give a try though.

Comment: Excellent! I would like to know your solution if you have the time? I am doing a lot of state management and complex workflows, so this has been a decent go to for myself. However, i would love to have an alternative to apply!

Comment: Sure. I have updated my question with the all my attempts (with Sudo code). Initial fails, and then the rise! ;)